# Notation for Byobu Keybinding Files

Tags: byobu

Does anyone know what notation is used to represent keyboard keys in Byobu's keybinding files (f-keys.screen etc)?

I know what keys I would like to change and have poured through the file trying to figure out which keys are represented by the notation you use but I can't decypher the compound structure for some of them. It looks like there are several symbols used for some commands and that is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there's two forms of notification, one for Byobu's **screen** backend, and the other for Byobu's **tmux** backend.

The **screen** backend uses GNU Screen's syntax, as described in its [manpage](http://manpg.es/screen.1), while the **tmux** backend uses Tmux's syntax, as described in its [manpage](http://manpg.es/tmux.1).

For **screen**, when I want to create a new keybinding, I usually open up a new terminal window *outside* of Byobu, and type:

```
$ cat >/dev/null
```

And then type some key combination, for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, and you should see on the screen:

```
^[[18;6~
```

That's the key code that you would need to put into your `~/.byobu/keybindings.screen`.

You'll use the `bindkey` command, and you'll want to bind that to one or more commands, as described in the screen [manpage](http://manpg.es/screen.1).

For **tmux**, the syntax is *way* easier!  Here, you can just use "S" for <kbd>Shift</kbd>, "C" for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, "M" for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.  Once again, it's described pretty thoroughly in the tmux [manpage](http://manpg.es/tmux.1).